# Find in maven where a property is defined

Tags: java, maven

I'm currently refactoring lots of pom.xml in various projects and git repo.
Sometimes, a pom in a project A will require an artifact defined in a project B in a version defined by a property :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact-from-b</artifactId>
    <version>${version.from.somewhere}</version>
</dependency>
```

Sometimes, the version property is not obviously defined in the pom itself or its parent pom. It can be hidden in a parent's parent's parent...

I'm currently trying to find a way to resolve easily properties like ${version.from.somewhere} and find where it is defined.

Any idea of any tool that can help me (apart from eclipse, which fails for some tricky properties) ?

Thanks !

Comment: The properties should be defined in the parent of that project or in the parent of the parent...?

Comment: mvn help:effective-pom

Comment: @question_maven_com The effective POM won't tell where the property is defined however.

Comment: What kind of "tricky properties" are you thinking about? Eclipse has always worked for me.

Comment: @khmarbaise : the properties can be defined anywhere. Sometimes it's in the project itself, sometimes it's defined in a pom in another project and it's hard to find which "artifact" brings them.

Comment: @question_maven_com : didn't know about this, it's quite interesting ! thanks

Comment: @Tunaki : The property I'm currently looking is a property defined in a control file (used to build debian package). The file is used by the jdeb maven plugin, and this plugin replaces the maven properties with the value. Eclipse cannot resolve this one as it's not in a pom. When I try to use the property in a pom, it doesn't work and it cannot resolve the property. While writing this, I find it weird that maven cannot use it in a pom...

Comment: @Tunaki  with mvn help:effective-pom, we can find the value of the version used by Maven

Comment: @question_maven_com Yes, but only the value, not where it was defined.

Comment: OK, I found where the property was. I had a dependency on something like that : <classifier>properties</classifier>.  This brings a properties file which is read by a maven-properties-plugin and loaded in maven env.

Answer (score 5):

There is a related answer here [Is there a way to trace origin of a property in maven pom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124917/is-there-a-way-to-trace-origin-of-a-property-in-maven-pom#57184511)

That suggest using `mvn help:effective-pom -Dverbose=true` then you can find comments like `com.example.model:2.1.0-SNAPSHOT`.

I tried it and it worked for me.

In my case, the property is defined in the pom of `com.example.model:2.1.0-SNAPSHOT` in line 407

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>com.example</groupId>  <!-- com.example.model:2.1.0-SNAPSHOT, line 405 -->
          <artifactId>model</artifactId>  <!-- com.example.model:2.1.0-SNAPSHOT, line 406 -->
          <version>1.0.6</version>  <!-- com.example.model:2.1.0-SNAPSHOT, line 407 -->
```

Comment: it doesn't give us trace of where it came from.

Comment: Yes, @HarshitPanchal, it does show the origin for properties: eg.

`<properties>
    <activemq.version>5.16.6</activemq.version>  <!-- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.7.14, line 29 -->
</properties>`