# How can I find out where a property was defined in a Maven build

Tags: maven

It seems that something in my Maven build is overriding a property that defines certain versions of some transitive dependency within a dependency that I don't control. The immediate effect is that some of the transitive dependencies cannot be resolved, since the module structure of the transitive dependency has changes between versions.

Is there a way to determine all the places where the property is (re-)defined so that I could figure out which parts of the build contribute to the problem?

Comment: `properties` section? DependencyManagement would be also a good location to look at...

Comment: Dupliicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669562/find-in-maven-where-a-property-is-defined (without answers).