# Is there a way to trace origin of a property in maven pom?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, dependency-management

I have a complex maven project with a lot of managed dependencies, and have a little problem tracing versions of these dependencies. For example, spring libraries' version is guided by a property value {spring.version} - but I have no idea which project this property is coming from.

Using mvn dependency:tree I can see the final result where all versions are resolved, but it does not go deep into detail to tell me where the winning dependency version is coming from, and why that version is a winner.

P.S. Version number is not coming from my parent pom.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-repositories-mojo.html    `mvn dependency:list-repositories`?

Comment: @Adonis not really. This will tell me WHAT is used, but does not tell me WHY.

Comment: Why is always a big question (as highlighted by your capital letters), so far I cannot tell you how to figure WHY some dependencies are in use with a certain version through maven

Answer (score 21):

You could give `help:effective-pom` a go. Just make sure that you use the `3.2.0` version (or later) together with the `-Dverbose=true` flag set. This will print out the source of the POM value.

To force the right version of the plugin:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

To use it:

```
%> mvn help:effective-pom -Dverbose=true
```

This will print out the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Generated by Maven Help Plugin on 2019-07-24T15:28:33+02:00            -->
<!-- See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/                -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Effective POM for project                                              -->
<!-- 'org.example:test-project:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'                          -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  <!-- org.example:test-project:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, line 5 -->
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  <!-- org.example:test-project:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, line 16 -->
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>  <!-- org.example:test-project:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, line 17 -->
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>  <!-- org.example:test-project:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, line 18 -->
    <relativePath />  <!-- org.example:test-project:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, line 19 -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>  <!-- org.example:test-project:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, line 7 -->
  <artifactId>test-project</artifactId>  <!-- org.example:test-project:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, line 8 -->
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>  <!-- org.example:test-project:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, line 9 -->
  <name>Test Project</name>  <!-- org.example:test-project:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, line 12 -->
  <description>Blabla.</description>  <!-- org.example:test-project:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, line 13 -->
  <url>https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/#/spring-boot-starter-parent/test-project</url>  <!-- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.0.5.RELEASE, line 14 -->
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>  <!-- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.5.RELEASE, line 12 -->
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0</url>  <!-- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.5.RELEASE, line 13 -->
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <developers>
    <developer>
      <name>Pivotal</name>  <!-- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.5.RELEASE, line 18 -->
      <email>info@pivotal.io</email>  <!-- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.5.RELEASE, line 19 -->
      <organization>Pivotal Software, Inc.</organization>  <!-- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.5.RELEASE, line 20 -->
      <organizationUrl>http://www.spring.io</organizationUrl>  <!-- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.5.RELEASE, line 21 -->
    </developer>
  </developers>
  <properties>
    <activemq.version>5.15.6</activemq.version>  <!-- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.5.RELEASE, line 28 -->
    <antlr2.version>2.7.7</antlr2.version>  <!-- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.5.RELEASE, line 29 -->
    <appengine-sdk.version>1.9.64</appengine-sdk.version>  <!-- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.5.RELEASE, line 30 -->
    <artemis.version>2.4.0</artemis.version>  <!-- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.5.RELEASE, line 31 -->
    <aspectj.version>1.8.13</aspectj.version>  <!-- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.5.RELEASE, line 32 -->
    ...
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  <!-- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.5.RELEASE, line 208 -->
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>  <!-- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.5.RELEASE, line 209 -->
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>  <!-- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.5.RELEASE, line 210 -->
      </dependency>
      ...
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: Be warned that the true origin from a transitive dependency may not be revealed. In my opinion, this is a method that can be descriptive but not definitive.